# В чем вести стриминг?

Tags: backend, видео, мобильная-разработка, streaming

Будет писаться мобильное приложение, которое должно получать видео в режиме реального времени. Типа началась трансляция - пошло изображение. Сейчас стоит вопрос через что это лучше организовать. Видео не приватные и как мне кажется проще всего не писать свой бэкенд, а воспользоваться чем-то типа Ютуба. Но нужно несколько идей для сравнения как это еще можно организовать. Как через аналогичные сервисы, так и через свой бэкенд. Может есть готовые реализации стримингового бэкенда, которые можно просто установить на свой сервер? Понимаю что писать его самому - довольно заморочно и нет смысла.